# 1986 HMC Hawkins Motor Coach on the P-30 Frame with a 454 BBC

Tags: starter, no-crank-no-start, motorhome, bbc-engine

I just replaced the water pump in my 1986 HMC Hawkins Motor Coach. It's got a 454 BBC on the P-30 Frame. With a new starter that was a week old, it refused to start. Turns out it was the solenoid on the starter, so I put a brand new starter in yesterday and it still refuses to start. No click and no Crank. Fuel pump comes on, but nothing else happens.

I'm at a loss....

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: On Chevrolet vehicles, there's a starter relay switch which is attached to the top of the steering column. There is a rod going from the ignition switch down to this. From this switch should be a thick purple wire. This wire goes down to the starter to energize the solenoid, which in turn energizes the starter. IF (and it's a big "if") your motorhome is setup like a Chevrolet, or uses the same wiring scheme, this should be how it is.  You can also jump directly from the large post on the solenoid to the small post which has wires going into it to make it turn over manually.

Comment: We tried to bump the starter last night and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you test the starter before you put it in the vehicle?

Comment: I did not. Considering that I have gone through four ULTIMA starters in the past year, I wouldn't be surprised if I got another bad one.

Comment: What condition are battery cables in? Negative battery  cable to chassis and/or engine block?

Comment: I'm going to have to get back to you on that after I get the new starter out so I can test it properly. All my wiring and connection points are good.

Comment: We have the new starter out and we'll be testing it when my batteries charge some. My dog's cat played with the radio and drained it.

Comment: Tested the starter and it tested good. So I don't know what to do now

Comment: Where would you find a relay if there is one?

Comment: Look to see if there is [something like this](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/chevrolet,1986,c20+suburban,5.7l+350cid+v8,1408508,electrical-switch+&+relay,ignition+starter+switch,4700) on the top side of the steering column. It is the ignition starter switch I was talking about above. It would have a long rod on it which would go back up the steering column attaching to the ignition switch which the key goes into. Mind you, this is just a SWAG trying to help you.

Comment: Okay so I found out that it was the Starter relay which was conveniently located on the bracket on top of the alternator. Was able to bump start it from there with a piece of wire. Replacing it in the morning.